# NGUI labels are fading out on iOS device

Tags: unity-game-engine, label, fadeout, ngui

I am facing a bizarre situation that is, I have made NGUI panel with sprites and labels and these are working fine on unity editor but when I make a build on iOS device sprites are working as expected but labels are being shown for 0.2 or 0.3 second and then fade out suddenly . can anybody tell me what may be the problem ?

Comment: That sounds like you simply have an alpha tween or something similar on a panel?

Comment: No I haven't used alpha tween. If I would have used it then I would face same problem in unity Editor

Comment: Is there any way in which you can share the project (or a slimmed down version only exhibiting the problem)?

Comment: the project is too large so i cant provide it online. I have found something . my UI panel on which these label are present has a big sprite on its background the problem is that the background sprite covering these label but not the other sprites or buttons. If I remove the background sprite these labels become visible. There should not be the "depth issue" i guess as my buttons and labels are of same depth.

Comment: This totally weired. Maybe you should try to make your labels' depth improved.At least not the same with your buttons, cause they didn't use the same texture.

Answer (score 0):

If your labels and sprite are on the same depth, then it probably is a depth issue.

The reason why it looks good in the editor, could be different z sorting on different platforms. On mobile platforms it could be even more random, on different runs.

If you want something to be above other widget, it should have higher depth value (assuming you are using the new 3.x.x NGUI), than you will be certainly sure that it will look good on all platforms.

On the older 2.x.x NGUI not only depth is important, but also a source texture (is it the same or are there two different textures) and a position z value.